# Logcat throws errors when creating a Dialog "token Null is not for an application"

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

According to `logcat` output, the app crashes at the point of creating `Dialog`. I tried to change the variable `reportAlertDialog` to be of type `AlertDialog` but i found that, some features/properties are not available such as `setcontentView`, but it is available when the variable is of type `Dialog`. anyways, the app crashes at this point and `logcat` output is rather inexplicable. Any suggestions?

JavaCode:

```
private void report(Bundle thisActivityBundle) {
            ...
                            ...
            if ( (reportAlertDialog != null) && (reportAlertDialog.isShowing()) ) {
                reportAlertDialog.cancel();
                Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "@report(): reportAlertDialogue Was Showing And Now Is Canceled");
            }

            String sortedKeys[] = {LOC_NAME_KEY, LOC_LAT_KEY, LOC_LNG_KEY, LOC_TIME_KEY, LOC_DATE_KEY, IMG_TITLE_KEY, IMG_PATH_KEY};
            String bundleVals [] = new String[sortedKeys.length];

            for (int i=0; i<sortedKeys.length; i++) {
                if (thisActivityBundle.containsKey(sortedKeys[i])) {
                    bundleVals[i] = thisActivityBundle.getString(sortedKeys[0]).toString();
                }else {
                    bundleVals[i] = "NULL";
                }
            }

            reportAlertDialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
            LayoutInflater reportAlertDialogLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
            View reportAlertDialogInflatedView = reportAlertDialogLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.report_dialog, null);

            reportAlertDialog.setContentView(reportAlertDialogInflatedView);

            int [] viewsRefsIds = {R.id.reportLocNameValue, R.id.reportLocLatValue, R.id.reportLocLngValue, R.id.reportTimeValue,
                    R.id.reportDateValue, R.id.reportImgTitleValue, R.id.reportImgPathValue
            };
            TextView [] viewsVars = new TextView[viewsRefsIds.length];

            TextView reportAlertDialogMSG = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(R.id.reportDialogMessageID);
            reportAlertDialogMSG.setText(REPORT_ALERT_DIALOG_MSG);

            for (int i=0; i<bundleVals.length; i++) {
                viewsVars[i] = (TextView) reportAlertDialog.findViewById(viewsRefsIds[i]);
                viewsVars[i].setText(bundleVals[i]);
            }

            reportAlertDialog.show();

        }
```

Logcat:

```
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): Process: com.example.meetingpointlocator_03, PID: 2396
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:540)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix$4.report(MeetingPointFix.java:307)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix$4.onClick(MeetingPointFix.java:240)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-24 08:06:01.317: E/AndroidRuntime(2396):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set the parameter for the dialog to this activity

```
    reportAlertDialog = new Dialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

I think it will work.